# Post request give me always this error: The default editor must be configured using the command `pref set editor.command.default "{commandLine}"`

Tags: asp.net

When I try to do a post request on the terminal with this command `post` I always receive this error *The default editor must be configured using the command `pref set editor.command.default "{commandLine}"`.*

this is my code:

```
    public IActionResult Create(int id)
    {  
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza(); 
        pizza.Name = "Pizza bona";
        pizza.IsGlutenFree = true;
        pizza.Id = 1;
        try
        {
            PizzaService.Add(pizza);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
```